# Building out an OpenStack lab and want fault tolerance

Tags: openstack

I want to move away from VMware and onto OpenStack for our development lab. This mini project is meant to be an opportunity to learn about OpenStack as part of a larger strategic move for the company that will be happening in 2025/2026.

One thing important to the DEV lab is that I want VMs to be fault-tolerant. Meaning, if a host were to go offline, I want VMs to fail over to one of the other running hosts. Is this possible to do without having a shared NAS/SAN? Is there a way we can have 3x separate hosts but have data stores replicate to each host?

Comment: Of course. Clustered filesystem, network shares, there are multiple possibilities. Recommendations are however off topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Hyperconverged Infrastructure on OpenStack. This means that Ceph nodes are deployed on the Compute nodes. You can configure to use the Controllers as Compute nodes too.

Comment: Would you happen to have any articles you can point me towards?

Comment: https://thenewstack.io/openstack-and-ceph-for-distributed-hyperconverged-edge-deployments/

Comment: Red Hat doc: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_openstack_platform/17.1/html/deploying_a_hyperconverged_infrastructure/index